# Interpretation of this Microsoft Document referring Visual Studio Project Installers and FTP site?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am reading this Microsoft Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/prerequisites-dialog-box?view=vs-2022 and I am bit confused and looking for some clarity about the following statement.

> Download prerequisites from the following location    Specifies that the prerequisite components be installed from the location that you enter. You can use the Browse button to select a location.

If I have a custom URL for a .NET Runtime installer would I be able to use that as my installer and let it download from there instead of from the vendor site which would be the Microsoft site for the .NET 6.0.20? Or is my interpretation of the document wrong and I can not include my own custom link for the installation of the target framework that I desire?

I would like to see if it possible to just have the application download the target exe from the FTP site without having to go to the vendor site for the link. If it is not possible is there a reason why my link is as such:

"https:\Ftp\site\installation_link.exe"

I tried running Setup.exe and it gave me an error saying that:

Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697210.